Can't enter product key for new Windows 11
I am trying to install a new unused Windows 11 Pro on a new unused motherboard.  It gets to the screen asking for the product key but it won't let me enter more than the first 5 characters.  It's like the input box is completely broken.  What am I doing wrong?

I think I figured it out.  I was using a wireless keyboard.  Out of desperation I dug out a wired keyboard and was able to enter the whole key without any trouble.

I've seen similar effects from an Apple wireless keyboard in windows, where the Num Lock key had to be pressed in order to have any input other than the invisible keypad.  There's no Num Lock key on it, so it had to be accomplished using a script

@MountainMan this was a regular PC keyboard that I've used for years.  Since it was able to generate keystrokes I never anticipated that it would be the source of the trouble.
